# Wordpress Custom plugin: Can't get file_put_contents to work

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am trying to create a plugin with a JSON file to store options data. I want the JSON file data replaced with data submitted from a form in the plugin. I have tried to use file_put_contents, but nothing changes in the JSON file. Please check my code below and tell me where I am getting it wrong.

```
function save_changes() {

    // check when the submit button is clicked

      if( isset( $_POST['f-submitted']) ) {
    
        // sanitize form values
        $campaign    = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["campaign"] );
        $api_key    = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["api_key"] );
        $api_url_s    = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["api_url_s"] );
        $api_url    = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["api_url"] );
        $api_msg    = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["api-msg"] );
        

        empty($_POST["email"]) ? $email   = get_option( 'admin_email' ) : $email   = sanitize_email( $_POST["email"] );
        
        $path = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/js/data.JSON';
        //wp_delete_file($path);
        $jsonString = file_get_contents($path);
        $data = json_decode($jsonString, true);
        
        
        $data["campaign"] = utf8_encode($campaign);
        $data["email"] = utf8_encode($email);
        $data["apiUrlS"] = utf8_encode($api_url_s);
        $data["apiUrl"] = utf8_encode($api_url);
        $data["apiKey"] = utf8_encode($api_key);
        $data["msg"] = utf8_encode($api_msg);
        
      
        $j_data = json_encode($data);
                
        
        
        try{
            
            
            file_put_contents($path, $j_data);
            echo '<p class="regular-text code" >Setings has been saved</p>';
            
        
            
        }catch(exception $e){
            
           echo '<p class="regular-text code" style="color:crimson;">Error: something went wrong</p>';
        } 
        
        
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the json file empty or has some content (but not expected content)?

Comment: @OzgurSar I had the json file seeded with some initial data and it just stays the same after running the code. Thanks

Comment: did you check it is even getting inside this if statement? `if( isset( $_POST['f-submitted']) )`

Comment: yes, i did. I even had the re-encoded json data outputted and it works fine. only the file_put_contents seem not to be working and it doesn't throw any errors as well

Comment: Did you check the permission of file? I would like to suggest 755 recursive permission.

Comment: You can use umask for what ZealousWeb suggested https://www.php.net/umask

Comment: Sorry for not responding earlier. I have tried the permission you suggested, but  it didn't work. I will try the umask option now. Thanks